# Determinant of specially structured block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

How do you compute the determinant of the following $nd \times nd$ block matrix?

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}A+B & A & A & \dots & A & A\\ A & A+B & A & \dots & A & A\\ A & A & A+B & \dots & A & A\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ A & A & A & \dots & A+B & A\\ A & A & A & \dots & A & A+B\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are $d \times d$ matrices.

Comment: Related post on MO: [Determinant of a $k \times k$ block matrix](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179377/determinant-of-a-k-times-k-block-matrix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has the same determinant as the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0 & \cdots & -B \\
0 & B & \cdots & -B \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
A & A & \cdots & A+B
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which has the same determinant as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & B & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
A & A & \cdots & nA+B
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is easy to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $B$ is invertible. Write

$$\begin{array}{rl} M &= \begin{bmatrix} A + B & A & \ldots & A\\ A & A + B & \ldots & A\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\A & A & \ldots & A + B \end{bmatrix}\\\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} B & O_d & \ldots & O_d\\ O_d & B & \ldots & O_d\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ O_d & O_d & \ldots & B \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} A \\ A\\ \vdots \\ A\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I_d \\ I_d\\ \vdots \\ I_d\end{bmatrix}^T\\\\ &= (I_n \otimes B) + (1_n \otimes A) (1_n \otimes I_d)^T\\\\ &= (I_n \otimes B) \left(I_{nd} + (I_n \otimes B^{-1}) (1_n \otimes A) (1_n \otimes I_d)^T\right)\end{array}$$

Using the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$\begin{array}{rl} \det (M) &= \det\left((I_n \otimes B) \left(I_{nd} + (I_n \otimes B^{-1}) (1_n \otimes A) (1_n \otimes I_d)^T\right)\right)\\\\ &= \det(I_n \otimes B) \cdot \det \left( I_{nd} + (I_n \otimes B^{-1}) (1_n \otimes A) (1_n \otimes I_d)^T\right)\\\\ &= \det(I_n \otimes B) \cdot \det \left( I_{d} + (1_n \otimes I_d)^T (I_n \otimes B^{-1}) (1_n \otimes A) \right)\\\\ &= \left(\det(B)\right)^n \cdot \det \left( I_{d} + n B^{-1} A \right)\\\\ &= \det(B^n) \cdot \det \left( I_{d} + n B^{-1} A \right)\\\\ &= \det \left( B^n + n B^{n-1} A \right)\end{array}$$

Comment: Nice use of Kronecker products!